# Problem with feature extraction and understanding of the task

Tags: python, nlp, perceptron

I am trying to finish my homework but have already been stuck for weeks, I don't really understand what should I do for the section part : Feature Extraction.

I put the screenshot below, if Anyone could help......
[1st Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZElu.png)
[2nd Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW4QQ.png)

For the first part,

```
import conllu
from conllu import parse

def read_conllu(filename):
    words_frGSD =[]
    upos_frGSD = []
    sentence_length = []
    index_new = 0 
    final_list = []
    with open(filename,'r') as fr_GSD:
        frGSDPar = parse(fr_GSD.read())
        #get the lenght of every sentence 
        for i in range(len(frGSDPar)):
            sentence_length.append(len(frGSDPar[i]))
        ## extract words 
        for word in frGSDPar:
            for i in range(len(word)):
                words_frGSD.append(word[i]['form'])
                upos_frGSD.append(word[i]['upos'])
        ## following the length to get the pair 
        for i in range(len(sentence_length)):
            word = []
            label = []
            lst1 = [] 
            sentence_length_total = sentence_length[i]
            word = words_frGSD[index_new:(index_new+sentence_length_total)]
            label = upos_frGSD[index_new:(index_new+sentence_length_total)]
            lst1.append(word)
            lst1.append(label)
            final_list.append(lst1)
            index_new = index_new + sentence_length_total

    return final_list,words_frGSD,upos_frGSD
```

I am just Python beginner, so the code is a little bit too redundant. With this code I finished my first part, but I don't know how to do with 2nd part